# How to get the checkbox value instantly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to watch the checkbox when it's checked in Angular

I have something like

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test[item.id]" ng-click="getID()" ng-checked="checkAll"/> {{item.Name}}
</div>
```

js

```
$scope.getID = function(id){
    console.log(id)  -> it always get the id and I only want to get id when the checkbox is  
                     -> chekced
}
```

I want to get ID only when the check box is checked. How do I do that? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change you `$scope.getID()` by an extra parameter `isChecked` to check if the item was checked or not. Another thing to notice is that your html lacks the required parameters of your function to get the `ID`.

e.g.

**Javascript**

```
$scope.getID = function(id, isChecked) {
  if(isChecked) {
    console.log('ID:', id, 'is checked');
  } else {
    console.log('ID:', id, 'is unchecked');
  }
}
```

**HTML**

change this:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test[item.id]" ng-click="getID()" ng-checked="checkAll"/> {{item.Name}}
```

to this:

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="item in items">
     <input type="checkbox" ng-model="test[item.id]" ng-click="getID(item.id, test[item.id])" ng-checked="checkAll"/> {{item.Name}}
</div>
```